# How can communicate between my Android module and Flutter Module?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-method-channel, flutter-android, flutter-engine

Currently, I have integrated flutter in my existing Android Module using Flutter cached Engine.

Is there a way that I can pass the data as we do in android using Bundles

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: @pskink No this is not the one I'm trying to Call from Existing Android Activity --> Flutter Screen which I have done but I want to pass the data.